# Specialized Crash with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to play a video using AVPlayer and adding a sublayer player to the main view. It works on my phone, but it is crashing on the iPhone 6 iOS 8.3

Below is the stacktrace. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Tether                         0x100157bbc specialized TetherDetailViewController.(playVideo in _76F367FEC7F2989028C7D8B91C1E249D)(NSURL) -> () (TetherDetailViewController.swift:127)
1  Tether                         0x100158544 partial apply for TetherDetailViewController.(viewWillAppear(TetherDetailViewController) -> (Bool) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (TetherDetailViewController.swift:38)
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1987f9994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1987f9954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1987fe20c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18693b7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1869398a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1868652d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
8  GraphicsServices               0x19007b6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
9  UIKit                          0x18b42afac UIApplicationMain + 1488
10 Tether                         0x1001209d0 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x198826a08 start + 4
```

This is the function that it says its crashing on:

```
private func playVideo(videoURL: NSURL) {
        if player == nil {
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
            player.actionAtItemEnd = .None
            let layer = AVPlayerLayer()
            layer.player = player
            layer.frame = videoView.frame
            //videoTitleLabel.text = currentTether.title
            //layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.containerView.frame.width, cell.containerView.frame.height)
            layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.tetherOrange().CGColor
            layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

            view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
            self.player = player
        }

        player.play()
        videoFinished = false
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "itemDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:self.player.currentItem)
    }
```

Comment: your preview layer is connected to a session, which has input devices which has the physical device. Are you running this on simulator? Sounds like somewhere else in your code where you set up the AVCaptureSession may be trying to access a camera device which won't be on the simulator.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey this is on the actual device. It's also playing a video from a url, not recording anything

Comment: When does it crash? The very first time the view appears? Or after hiding it and coming back to it perhaps? Any other details you can give us about when / how the crash happens? Also, which line is line 127?